# How can I remove TickTick's icon from the menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

TickTick will not allow their users to remove its icon from the menubar in macOS. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in Terminal:

```
strings -ao /Applications/TickTick.app/Contents/Resources/Assets.car | grep menubar_icon_task@2x.png | awk "{print \$1}" | xargs echo 232+ | bc | \
xargs -I{} echo "printf '\x01' | dd of=/Applications/TickTick.app/Contents/Resources/Assets.car bs=1 conv=notrunc seek={}" | sh
```

It will narrow the menubar icon down so much that it will become invisible. Ctrl+'mouse drag' the icon to the left most place.

**Explanation:**
*strings* finds the position of the icon in the asset container, *echo* and *bc* move a few bytes forward to get to the position that is responsible for the width of the icon. *printf* and *dd* set that byte to 1 for minimum width.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of the various steps this takes?